# Sony VAIO VGN-SZ240P Laptop Fan Control?

Tags: fan, sony-vaio, noise

I have a VAIO VGN-SZ240P that I'm running WinXP SP3 on. In general it is a fine machine, but the cooling fan is quite loud. Does anybody know of a tool that I can use to view and manage the fan speed? I tried the latest SpeedFan beta, but it doesn't see the fan.

Comment: if speedfan can't see it then that should dent your hopes a lot.  Is there any option in power management?  some laptops like toshiba I think have a special power management like icon in control panel(toshiba power  saver or something) with settings for it.  I  know yours is a Sony though. So maybe it doesn't.

Comment: As I alluded to below, this is a mechanical problem (a loose wire banging against the fan shroud) and so there's no software fix.

Comment: I had a [similar problem](http://superuser.com/questions/659716/is-a-noisy-laptop-fan-caused-by-dirt-on-the-fan) with a Sony Vaio. It's still banging sounding loud. I switched to an Asus laptop. The solution in out case is probably to leave the computer to a hardware technician OTC than can take an examine the problem and hopefully clean and solve the problem. I tried using cleaning spray and that didn't work.

Comment: @NiklasRosencrantz this is a bit late but see daniel hick's answer

Answer (score 1):

Does this apply to you?

http://www.tomsguide.com/us/exit-the-sony-vaio-t,review-607-11.html

looks like it may have a power saving option, with fan speed options. icon possibly in control panel.

somebody here mentioned  for his VAIO
http://www.notebookforums.com/thread99131-2.html
"If you open up the VAIO control panel, youll see power management, click on the +, then select power options, when the power options properties opens up click on the

"VAIO POWER MANAGEMENT" tab, look under system, thermal and you can choose "performance" or "quiet".

I have a BZ VAIO and my fan was very loud but since I put it on quiet its hardly noticeable, my temps are around 95f, very cool!!"

Comment: Either that Control panel is not available for my VAIO or I haven't found where to download it from Sony. It is not on my machine.

Comment: @Peter Loron   If speedfan can't control the fan then I suspect no software will. 'cos I haven't heard of speedfan failing to change fan speed, and then some other software working.

Comment: @Peter Loron  maybe rmclock.   I read somebody wrote http://www.notebookforums.com/thread99131.html "you lower your vcore, your cpu runs cooler, your fan runs less, the only way outside of that i know how to control the fan is linux".  I dunno what he's getting at with linux. But maybe rmclock can lower your vcore, and/or processor speed and might cause a difference.

Comment: Some Sony's do have software, this is an update from sony for those that do have v1 apparently. http://esupport.sony.com/US/perl/swu-download.pl?mdl=VGNTXN25N&upd_id=2530&os_id=29  "Sony® VAIO® Power Management Utility Update"    And it doesn't mention your model of laptop. That doesn't mean there isn't another for your laptop..

Comment: I do not think the power management utility exists for your laptop, since you can't see it despite info on where it is.. And also, look at these two links. This laptop has it listed. Yours doesn't http://esupport.sony.com/US/perl/swu-list.pl?mdl=VGNTXN25N    http://esupport.sony.com/perl/swu-list.pl?mdl=VGNSZ240P#div_pos_116

Comment: I suppose if desperate and you've tried many things.. you could hack it open and attach a fan controller. i've never done that but it'd work. if you don't break the laptop.

Answer (score 0):

Is it running Hot? You may need to clean the fan and heatsink.

Here is an article, not for Sony but you will get the general idea.

http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?lc=en&dlc=en&cc=us&docname=c01657439

.

Comment: I just took the whole thing apart and cleaned it. No issues there.

Comment: Usually Notebook fan problems are one of 3 things, overheating (heatsink problems, etc), bios issue (only Sony can fix this with an update) or a motherboard is defective.

Answer (score 0):

What if you plug in a laptop cooling pad underneath your PC?  A good one can reduce your CPU's temperature by five degrees Celsius or so.  (I've never used one; I based that claim on a [CNet review](http://reviews.cnet.com/docks-stands/antec-notebook-cooler/4505-19213_7-30634900-2.html) of one such pad.)  I don't know much about hardware, but maybe your laptop will detect this cooling effect and slow down its fan?

Disclosure:  I have no connection with Antec or CNet.

Answer (score 0):

If you work in a dusty area, like Delhi, India. You should open you PC and clean the Fan, that's the best way to control your fan. I've to do it each 5 month, you PC will get lower heat and lower fan speed

Answer (score 0):

A bit late, but Sony admitted that it shipped some defective fans and added a 2-year extended warranty for fan noise for some models.

Answer (score 0):

Check this

http://ubuntu42.blogspot.gr/2011/03/quiet-down-noisy-fan-sony-vaio.html

works very well (quiter, cooler, faster)

Answer (score 0):

This is what i use on my laptop: [link](http://www.hwinfo.com/download64.html)
It should work for you to. You have there manual fan control and you can set it up for any speed you want. 
Just be careful with it!