# Is a noisy laptop fan caused by dirt on the fan?

Tags: windows-7, laptop, fan, sony-vaio

I got a Sony Vaio laptop VPCSA and its fan is noisy intermittently. At times it is very noisy and at other times it is pretty quite. I wonder whether this is caused by dirt on the fan that I can clean or leave the laptop to a computer repair shop so that they can service is? Or do you think that the noisiness from the fan is caused by some other factor than dirt since the noise is intermittent and not all the time?

### Update

I see there're some more suggestions how to fic the problem in another question [Sony VAIO VGN-SZ240P Laptop Fan Control?](https://superuser.com/questions/226301/sony-vaio-vgn-sz240p-laptop-fan-control)

Comment: Change the fan ASAP.

Comment: @NiklasRosencrantz - You spelled fix incorrectly in your last update.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While it's possible that dirt in a fan could potentially cause noise, what's much more likely is that the bearing(s) in the fan are starting to fail or otherwise seize. This creates a grinding noise that can get progressively worse if not taken care of. Eventually the fan may stop spinning altogether, and then you'd have more to worry about than the fan.

It's also possible that the noise you're hearing is from the hard drive, but if it is noticeably loud it's most likely the fan.

If you're not comfortable opening the laptop up and inspecting/replacing parts, I would suggest taking it into the shop.

Answer (score 2):

I'd say bad bearing - the sound going noisy and quiet is due to the fan shifting around somewhat. It can also be lower pitched depending. Youtube has quite a few examples [such as this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QkCLubSukzI). The fan may last a while but at the end of the day, its a race between your patience, and the fan dying. Get it fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Yes very true, but sometimes there could be another reason along with the dirt, first try to blow out the dirt/dust from the fan, and see if the noise is reduced, if there is no reduction in noise then you must consult a maintenance service.

Answer (score 0):

I have one of these and the fan -is- very noisy at times, and was when it was brand new.  But there is a BIOS update that is supposed to help.  My model's updates are here:
http://esupport.sony.com/US/p/model-home.pl?mdl=VPCSA31FX&LOC=3#/downloadTab

and one of the items noted in the BIOS update is "Reduces fan noise"

(They also sometimes run a bit hot; I use mine on a good cooling pad, which keeps the internal fan noise down a bit too.)